# Cordova(phonegap):- how to get mobile CallLog?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing mobile application using cordova like, send **Mobile Call Log** history.

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use this

Android only (help with IOS welcome) cordova plugin to access the call history on a device.
[call history](https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin)

Comment: the usage of that plugin is not defined !